# program crashes when debbuged with GDB but not when run with it

Tags: assembly, gdb

I am working on a simple crack-me program, it can be downloaded [here](http://wikiufox.no-ip.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=writeup:hackingweek2015:crackme-02.rar), the goal is to find the password, from what I understood, the program is modifying itself and then compares the password entered with the real one.

When I run the program without GDB, it works.

When I start gdb, replace ptrace with a one of my own through `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./ptrace.so` and run the program it works .

When I add a breakpoint after the first read and take it stepi by stepi, it ends with a segfault. Let me explain how I do it.

Here is the assembly after the read statement (I entered my password) :

```
0x8048563:  mov    esp,ebp
   0x8048565:   mov    edx,eax
   0x8048567:   dec    edx
   0x8048568:   mov    BYTE PTR [eax+0x80484a0],0x0
   0x804856f:   mov    esi,0x80485a4    <- gets the code at this address
   0x8048574:   mov    edi,esi
   0x8048576:   mov    ecx,0x15
   0x804857b:   lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]    
   0x804857c:   xor    al,0xaa             <-- XORs the code with something
   0x804857e:   call   0x8048583     <-- I dont understand what is the purpose of calling something that is executed right after but that is not the point
   0x8048583:   pop    ebx
   0x8048584:   add    ebx,0x7
   0x8048587:   jmp    ebx
   0x8048589:   call   0x8d9cc30e
   0x804858e:   add    al,0x8
   0x8048590:   int3   
   0x8048591:   jne    0x8048595
   0x8048593:   inc    al
   0x8048595:   stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
   0x8048596:   loop   0x804857b
   0x8048598:   mov    esi,0x80484a1
   0x804859d:   mov    edi,0x80485ae
   0x80485a2:   mov    ecx,edx
   0x80485a4:   push   es       <--- Code being modified
   0x80485a5:   xchg   BYTE PTR [eax+0x4880df04],ch
   0x80485ab:   push   edx
   0x80485ac:   inc    ecx
   0x80485ad:   mov    eax,ds:0xcefedefb
   0x80485b2:   out    dx,eax
   0x80485b3:   cdq    
   0x80485b4:   int3   
   0x80485b5:   retf
```

After setting my Breakpoint, I run the program step  by step until I get out of the code modifying loop and display the asm code :

```
0x8048598:  mov    esi,0x80484a1
   0x804859d:   mov    edi,0x80485ae
   0x80485a2:   mov    ecx,edx
   0x80485a4:   lods   eax,DWORD PTR ds:[esi]  <---final real code
   0x80485a5:   sub    eax,0x2b760403
   0x80485aa:   jecxz  0x80485a5
   0x80485ac:   in     al,dx            <-- Here the code crashes and stops working for some reason
   0x80485ad:   or     al,0x52
   0x80485af:   jne    0x8048606
   0x80485b1:   gs
   0x80485b2:   inc    esi
   0x80485b3:   xor    al,0x67
   0x80485b5:   bound  esi,QWORD PTR [ebx]
   0x80485b7:   arpl   WORD PTR [ecx],ax
   0x80485b9:   mov    ebp,esp
   0x80485bb:   sub    esp,0x4
   0x80485be:   and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x80485c1:   add    esp,0x4
   0x80485c4:   push   0x80485ef
   0x80485c9:   call   0x8048350
   0x80485ce:   mov    esp,ebp
   0x80485d0:   xor    eax,eax
   0x80485d2:   jmp    0x80485ee
   0x80485d4:   mov    ebp,esp
   0x80485d6:   sub    esp,0x4
   0x80485d9:   and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x80485dc:   add    esp,0x4
   0x80485df:   push   0x80485f7
   0x80485e4:   call   0x8048340
   0x80485e9:   mov    esp,ebp
   0x80485eb:   xor    eax,eax
   0x80485ed:   inc    eax
   0x80485ee:   ret
```

now running stepi gives me :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------registers---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
b'\x1b[;32mEAX\x1b[0m: 0x8bc662e \n\x1b[;32mEBX\x1b[0m: \x1b[;34m0x804858a\x1b[0m --> 0x85983d80 \n\x1b[;32mECX\x1b[0m: 0x9 (b\'\\t\')\n\x1b[;32mEDX\x1b[0m: 0x9 (b\'\\t\')\n\x1b[;32mESI\x1b[0m: \x1b[;34m0x80484a5\x1b[0m ("56789")\n\x1b[;32mEDI\x1b[0m: \x1b[;34m0x80485ae\x1b[0m ("RuUeF4gb3c\\001\\211\\345\\203", <incomplete sequence \\354>...)\n\x1b[;32mEBP\x1b[0m: \x1b[;35m0xffffd5fc\x1b[0m --> \x1b[;31m0xf7e34a83\x1b[0m (<__libc_start_main+243>:\tmov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax)\n\x1b[;32mESP\x1b[0m: \x1b[;35m0xffffd5fc\x1b[0m --> \x1b[;31m0xf7e34a83\x1b[0m (<__libc_start_main+243>:\tmov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax)\n\x1b[;32mEIP\x1b[0m: \x1b[;34m0x80485ac\x1b[0m --> 0x75520cec'
[-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------code-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
   0x80485a4:   lods   eax,DWORD PTR ds:[esi]
   0x80485a5:   sub    eax,0x2b760403
   0x80485aa:   jecxz  0x80485a5
=> 0x80485ac:   in     al,dx
   0x80485ad:   or     al,0x52
   0x80485af:   jne    0x8048606
   0x80485b1:   gs
   0x80485b2:   inc    esi
[----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------stack-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
00:0000| ebp esp 0xffffd5fc --> 0xf7e34a83 (<__libc_start_main+243>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax)
01:0004|         0xffffd600 --> 0x1 
02:0008|         0xffffd604 --> 0xffffd694 --> 0xffffd7d7 ("/root/current/c"...)
03:0012|         0xffffd608 --> 0xffffd69c --> 0xffffd7f0 ("XDG_SESSION_ID="...)
04:0016|         0xffffd60c --> 0xf7feacea (add    ebx,0x12316)
05:0020|         0xffffd610 --> 0x1 
06:0024|         0xffffd614 --> 0xffffd694 --> 0xffffd7d7 ("/root/current/c"...)
07:0028|         0xffffd618 --> 0xffffd634 --> 0xf92bd643 
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: stack, code, data, heap, rodata, value
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
0x080485ac in ?? ()
```

Is there something I am not doing properly? What is the difference between running the code with breakpoints and without? I saw in an article that this is a strange behavior, the makers of the crack me do not have this problem.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : without the breakpoint on 0x8048598 the program finishes without crashing.

Comment: Not the answer to Your question, but regarding to this line, which You do not understand, (  0x804857e:   call   0x8048583     <-- I dont understand what is the purpose of calling something that is executed right after but that is not the point
   0x8048583:   pop    ebx), this makes sense. The call instruction puts the address of the next instruction on stack, Pop just retrieves this.  usually this is done in shellcoding, when trying to access not-null-terminated strings.

Comment: @icbytes Thanks for the explanations, my goal is to learn more about assembly, every piece of information is highly valuable to me.

Comment: Then I recommend this site. This book is relatively old, but mostly all of the basics covered there, did not  change until now, especially the first six chapters will inform You about the NECESSARY basics( memory layout, adressing modes,  opcode represantation, etc....) http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf

Comment: I think I know why it does not work, the answer might just be in the question I am working on it and probably post it before tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a breakpoint with GDB adds an instruction, the one set before the code modifies itself moved all instruction addresses, therefore the modified code was different, and debugging it resulted in a undefined behavior.